# Routing Error No route matches "/users/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My name is Juan I'm from Spain and this is my first post. Thank you.

I following the Ruby on Rails tutorial of Michael Hartl in the chapter 8.

My problem is that to create the form for signup users in this chapter.

He say that action go to **"action=/users"** but my code I can see it with the firebug the action go to:

**`action="/users/new".`**

Then when I go click to sign up button the action go to action="/users/new" and the next error:

**Routing Error
No route matches "/users/new"**

I have not errors in rspec spec/ or autotest its all OK!!.

Can you help me for this problem? The helper used its "form_for"

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please update your question and show your `routes.rb` file and your `form_for` code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

Ok. I've checked the code of the tutorial. The source of the problem is the object you pass to `form_for`. Please, check if your users_controller's new action has this line:

```
@user = User.new
```

This line creates a new AR object, but doesn't save it to the DB. So when you pass it to  `form_for`, Rails knows it should generate a form for create action (POST /users).

https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app Here is the full source code of the tutorial application. You might find it useful. It gets updated sometimes to fix bugs and typos.

And one last thing. Have you tried restarting your web-server?

Comment: Thank you for your response. But where I should change the code to form_tag '/users'. In that file?

Because I dont see in tutorial a place where change it.

Comment: I've updated my answer, please check it out. If it doesn't help, post some code (view, controller, routes) - maybe there's a typo or something.

Comment: Thank you very much I had in the code: @user = "User.new" instead @user = User.new within quotes. I'm dork :(

The problem have been fixed. Thank you very much to Bassneck, Nick and All Stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 2):

Do you have

```
resources :users
```

in your routes.rb?

Comment: Yes I have resources :users in config/routes.rb :D